# Linux Bash Shell Command in Windows Powershell

Tags: linux, windows, bash, powershell, nginx

So the following command in Linux is to order a Nginx access.log file by those making the most requests.

```
'awk '{ print $1 }' access.log | uniq -c | sort -nr | more'
```

What it the equivalent for this command in Windows Powershell ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code translation service. Please state what you have tried and what *specific* thing you don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content access.log | ForEach-Object { $_.split()[0] -as [IPAddress] } | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Unique -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
```

or

```
gc access.log |%{ $_.Split()[0] -as [IPAddress] } | sort -U |%{ "$_" }
```

1. Read the file
2. Process it line by line
3. Split on spaces and take the first element
4. Cast it to an IPAddress type so it will sort numerically
5. Sort and deduplicate one way or another
6. Get the string representation of the [IPAddress] back out

NB. your code doesn't do what you claim; you need to be sorting first, before `uniq`, as it only removes consecutive duplicates, not all duplicates.